# Why does my regex do the matching as expect, but shows the rest of the content at the end?

Tags: php, regex

So, I got this code:

```
function PCRT ($input) {
    if (preg_match('/youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([^\&\?\/]+)/', $input, $id)) {
        echo '1<pre>'; print_r($id); echo '</pre>';
    } else if (preg_match('/youtube\.com\/embed\/([^\&\?\/]+)/', $input, $id)) {
        echo '2<pre>'; print_r($id); echo '</pre>';
    } else if (preg_match('/youtube\.com\/v\/([^\&\?\/]+)/', $input, $id)) {
        echo '3<pre>'; print_r($id); echo '</pre>';
    } else if (preg_match('/youtu\.be\/([^\&\?\/]+)/', $input, $id)) {
        echo '4<pre>'; print_r($id); echo '</pre>';
    } else {   
        return 'no match';
    }
}

echo PCRT(' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id tristique nisi. Praesent dolor nulla, auctor eu consequat quis, molestie non augue. Proin fermentum, metus et mattis convallis, lorem nunc posuere justo, sed posuere quam lacus ut felis. Vestibulum auctor ante sed eros pulvinar rutrum. Sed et pretium nisl. Suspendisse sed risus odio. Donec eu sodales est, vitae euismod justo. Cras tincidunt eros nisl, ac convallis lorem cursus nec. Nam malesuada, mi et dictum placerat, nulla nunc auctor dui, in sollicitudin metus purus non felis. Nulla lacinia pretium dolor, sit amet egestas lacus vulputate a. Integer sagittis libero justo, dignissim aliquet orci aliquet ut. Suspendisse a est ullamcorper libero vulputate bibendum eu eu massa. Phasellus nunc libero, gravida ac aliquet sed, pellentesque vel ipsum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris at mauris aliquam, consectetur nulla ac, tempus tortor. http://youtube.com/v/123456874145

Nunc tempor neque sed libero sodales, eu malesuada justo pretium. Integer ac dolor sit amet eros volutpat pulvinar. Cras pharetra accumsan metus. Proin at risus commodo sapien fermentum ullamcorper. Suspendisse ornare varius est, eget condimentum lectus sagittis vitae. Curabitur a massa nec ligula sodales fringilla. Morbi vestibulum rutrum risus. In sit amet turpis ut lacus dapibus posuere sed sit amet metus. Phasellus et posuere lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas vitae mi sit amet neque pharetra mollis. Mauris lorem est, luctus id leo nec, laoreet eleifend augue. Sed posuere nisl non nisl congue blandit a quis orci. Vestibulum sit amet magna sit amet turpis ultricies dictum. ');
```

Now the problem is its resulting:

```
3

Array
(
    [0] => youtube.com/v/123456874145

Nunc tempor neque sed libero sodales, eu malesuada justo pretium. Integer ac dolor sit amet eros volutpat pulvinar. Cras pharetra accumsan metus. Proin at risus commodo sapien fermentum ullamcorper. Suspendisse ornare varius est, eget condimentum lectus sagittis vitae. Curabitur a massa nec ligula sodales fringilla. Morbi vestibulum rutrum risus. In sit amet turpis ut lacus dapibus posuere sed sit amet metus. Phasellus et posuere lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas vitae mi sit amet neque pharetra mollis. Mauris lorem est, luctus id leo nec, laoreet eleifend augue. Sed posuere nisl non nisl congue blandit a quis orci. Vestibulum sit amet magna sit amet turpis ultricies dictum. 
    [1] => 123456874145

Nunc tempor neque sed libero sodales, eu malesuada justo pretium. Integer ac dolor sit amet eros volutpat pulvinar. Cras pharetra accumsan metus. Proin at risus commodo sapien fermentum ullamcorper. Suspendisse ornare varius est, eget condimentum lectus sagittis vitae. Curabitur a massa nec ligula sodales fringilla. Morbi vestibulum rutrum risus. In sit amet turpis ut lacus dapibus posuere sed sit amet metus. Phasellus et posuere lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas vitae mi sit amet neque pharetra mollis. Mauris lorem est, luctus id leo nec, laoreet eleifend augue. Sed posuere nisl non nisl congue blandit a quis orci. Vestibulum sit amet magna sit amet turpis ultricies dictum. 
)
```

What I want to do, is only to get the full link and also the id. Not the rest of the content. Since im very bad at regex, still. Then I dont know the correct way to stop matching it. Thought, if the content has multiple links, then I would like to get them too.. Just the `Nunc tempor neque sed libero sodales...` part there is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match('/youtube\.com\/v\/([^\&\?\/]+)/', $input, $id)
```

This part:

```
([^\&\?\/]+)
```

Is the part that's matching. It's looking for multiple characters, that aren't (the initial `^` negates the range) ampersands; question marks; or slashes. And because none of those characters are in the rest of the string, it matches everything, right to the end.

To fix it, there are a couple of options:

```
preg_match('/youtube\.com\/v\/([^\&\?\/\s]+)/', $input, $id)
```

Will stop when it gets to a space (`\s` matches whitespace, which also includes tabs and newlines)

```
preg_match('/youtube\.com\/v\/(\d+)/', $input, $id)
```

Will match just numbers (`\d` matches a number) - I don't know if YouTube IDs are always numbers, but your sample one is.

**Edit**:

There are a couple of ways you can make this more flexible; you can do it with regex, but those will make it more complex. What I'd suggest instead is running `$input` through `str_replace`, so it will strip out the parts of the URL you're not sure about:

```
$input = str_replace ('http://', '', $input);       // remove http://
$input = str_replace ('https://', '', $input);      // ... and https://
$input = str_replace ('www.', '', $input);          // ... and www.
```

That will leave you with a properly formatted string in $input that you can then parse normally.

Comment: You're welcome. Regular expressions do get easier, I promise.

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about it - you're looking for strings that contain `youtube.com` and variants, so it shouldn't matter if they start `www` or not, or whether they're `http` or `https`.

Comment: What I basically am looking for, is a correct variable, that understands that in that spot might be whatever included. In some spots `.*` works. But in front they dont.. You see, the youtube.com/etc will be replaced with a iframe. And if there is http://www in front, it matches, but will leave http://www in front of the iframe. I also tried all things with `|` as i understand that is the **or** variable. But I cannot figure this out. Atm I simply added an array as the preg's search and multiple regexes:D

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas - I think I get what you mean - does the edit help any?